# Jquery slow hiding/show text, photo, object, etc. Min-height 200px

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

Have some jquery script that must hide some text, objects, photos, etc.. The script hiding everything, but i need to show only 200px, then after clicking "more" - show 100%. (jquery lib i include) What i'm doing wrong? Thankx to all.

Here is a script:

```
 <span id="hello-bigtext">Some big text, objects, photos, etc</span>
 <div id="hello-more">more</div>
 <div id="hello-less" >less</div>


<script>
$("#hello-bigtext").hide("slow");
$("#hello-less").hide("slow");

$("#hello-more").click( function() {
    $("#hello-bigtext").show("slow");
    $("#hello-less").show("slow");
    $("#hello-more").hide("slow");
});

$("#hello-less").click( function() {
    $("#hello-bigtext").hide("slow");
    $("#hello-less").hide("slow");
    $("#hello-more").show("slow");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $("#hello_bigtext").slideUp(600);
  $("#hello_less").slideUp(600);

  $("#hello_more").click( function() {
    $("#hello_bigtext").slideDown(600);
    $("#hello_less").slideDown(600);
    $("#hello_more").slideUp(600);
  });

  $("#hello_less").click( function() {
    $("#hello_bigtext").slideUp(600);
    $("#hello_less").slideUp(600);
    $("#hello_more").slideDown(600);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="hello_bigtext" style="border-style:solid; height:200px; background-color:red; cursor:pointer;">Some big text, objects, photos, etc</div>
 <div id="hello_more" style="border-style:solid; height:200px; background-color:Yellow; cursor:pointer;">more</div>
 <div id="hello_less" style="border-style:solid; height:200px; background-color:green; cursor:pointer;">less</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But your example hiding everything too, on clicking more, your script show only 200px, But i need that initially must 200px, than after clicking "more" - show everything hiding before

Comment: Nothing changes. Everything is hiding. When "show" the click function "to less" not working. Maybe you have another desicion for my example?

Comment: Thank you... That's not what i need.. but i think i modified it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe so?

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $("#hello_bigtext").animate({height:0 , opacity:0},600);
  $("#hello_more").animate({height:200, opacity:1},600);
  $("#hello_less").animate({height:0 , opacity:0},600);

  $("#hello_more").click( function() {
     $("#hello_more").animate({height:0, opacity:0},600,function(){
          $("#hello_bigtext").animate({height:200, opacity:1},600,function(){
             $("#hello_less").animate({height:200, opacity:1},600);
           });
     });
  });

  $("#hello_less").click( function() {
     $("#hello_bigtext").animate({height:0, opacity:0},600,function(){
        $("#hello_less").animate({height:0, opacity:0},600,function(){
               $("#hello_more").animate({height:200, opacity:1},600);
        });
     });
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="hello_bigtext" style="border-style:solid; height:400px; background-color:red; cursor:pointer;">Some big text, objects, photos, etc</div>
 <div id="hello_more" style="border-style:solid; height:400px; background-color:Yellow; cursor:pointer;">more</div>
 <div id="hello_less" style="border-style:solid; height:400px; background-color:green; cursor:pointer;">less</div>
```

Comment: no no no no... In "bigtext" there is a div with some photo, text, objects